# Port from python code (opencv) to java (android)

Tags: java, android, python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to translate my python code (for opencv image-processing) to android

This is my python code

```py
image = cv2.imread("x.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 200, 50)
cv2.imwrite("edged.jpg", edged)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None
print (len(cnts))

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if the contour has four vertices, then we have found
    # the thermostat display
    if len(approx) == 4:
        displayCnt = approx

        break

output = four_point_transform(image, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))
```

and here is my java code

```java
                Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, src, new Size(5,5),0);
                Imgproc.Canny(src,src,50,200);

                List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
                Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
                Imgproc.findContours(src, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                hierarchy.release();
                sortContoursByArea(contours);


                for(int c = 0; c < contours.size(); c++)
                {
                    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
                    MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(c).toArray());
                    double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f,  true)*0.02;
                    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

                    if (approxCurve.toArray().length==4){
                        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );
                        // Get bounding rect of contour
                        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);

                        src = new Mat(src2, rect);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,rect.width+" "+rect.x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

this is my image after some processing

Edged Image :

[image: edged image]

(looks good)

and here is what i get in python (This is required output) and what i get in java

Result

[image: result]

how can i get the same result in java

**edit**

In  `MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );` 
i use `points.dump()` and i see that the 4 points are in the correct position

my problem is here

```java
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
src = new Mat(src2, rect);
```

i thing it tries to create a square using x,y,width,height but it's not!
How can i crop my image using the four MatOfPoint points coordinates?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using same OpenCV version for Python and Android? If yes, then try `Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);` in case of Android. The gray output is different for `BGR` and `RGB` image.

Comment: opencv in python is v4 (the tutorial i followed to write the code was about v3) and in android 3.4.3 (higher available i thing)! Changing cvtColor didn't do anything, i thing the problem is inside for !

Comment: Then you need to debug the output at each step.

Comment: i did , see edit in my post please